# htaccess set $_GET['name'] => domain.com/$1

Tags: .htaccess

Test on my server.

eg.

php url = http://domain.com/game.php?game=gta5

I need change to  http://domain.com/gta5

tried it. buy no work

RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/game.php?game=$1

now results: 
http://domain.com/game.php?game=game.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^favicon\.ico
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^favicon\.png
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ game.php?game=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Request from user: http://domain.com/gta5
Request redirect to: http://domain.com/game.php?game=gta5